# What is good notation for the image of a curve on a manifold?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, notation

What is a good notation for the image of a curve $\gamma$ on a Riemannian manifold? Is there some notation like $\mathrm{Im}\gamma$? (I have only seen this for matrices in linear algebra). I have many curves so I don't want to introduce a set $\mathcal{S}$ for each image.

Note: I write for a readership in dynamical systems theory who knows some basics of differential geometry and topology.

Comment: There is nothing close to a standard notation. Frequently, curves are denoted $c$; it is fine to use ${\mathrm Im}(c)$ for the image. You can also use $c$ for the curve and $\gamma$ for its image. Also, use subscripts to distinguish different curves.

Comment: I've seen $[\gamma]$ used in several textbooks on complex analysis.

Comment: @Calum. Thank you. I considered this also. At first I liked $[\gamma]$ because it suggests the equivalence of different parametrizations. However, then I realised that some different curves that are not reparametrizations will belong to the same equivalence class, for example any closed curve that overlaps itself multiple times.